# Jquery print() not showing color in google chrome print prview

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, printing

I am using this code to print option on my web page

```
$(document).on('click','.print_report',function(){
    $(this).closest('.blockOne').print();
});
```

But it display only black and white content. I try inline color style but it show only black and white. How I make my page print in color?

Comment: @Rony it show only in black and white in google chrome print preview

Comment: add ur css below in media query like .@media print { color: #fff; }

Comment: @user3040610 means all css files

Comment: no color styles into that media query

Comment: I added in my css file @media print { .greenColor {color: #7cb342;} } but nothing happen